# Temporarily make quick fixes to a NuGet package source

Tags: .net, debugging, nuget

My application consists of multiple projects. Some of them have a reference to a NuGet package. All of the code is written by me, so I have the source and the debug symbols on my computer. While I can set breakpoints and step into the code from a NuGet package, I cannot make any changes to it.

I could replace the NuGet package references with the actual compiled DLL, but the NuGet package also has references that I lose with the package reference. I'd have to rebuild the whole dependency tree which is a lot of work for a quick experiment.

I also tried leaving the NuGet references untouched and just add an additional reference to the compiled DLL with modifications, but the additional reference was ignored. My local changes were not executed. Instead the NuGet DLL was used as before.

So when I'm debugging a system consisting of an app and a NuGet package, both with other dependencies, what's the easiest and quickest way to change that code and immediately build and test it?

Creating a new commit and version of the NuGet package to put it in my local package source is complicated and leaves many unnecessary commits in the NuGet's repository. Recreating the same version and deleting the computer's package cache is also stupid. Isn't there a simple and elegant way to debug NuGet packages, or are they a solid wall you cannot jump over during the development process? Is it like you make a NuGet package and that's it, you never change it again until you release a new version?