# How do I quickly make changes to custom libraries that generate and consume NuGet packages?

Tags: .net, nuget

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851909/temporarily-make-quick-fixes-to-a-nuget-package-source). I have a solution, `A`, which contains projects `B` and `C`:

```
A
|-B  ---> B.nupkg
|          ^
|-C  ------|
```

In the past, `C` used a project reference to `B`. Now, I've converted `B` so that it generates a NuGet package when I build (`<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` in `B.csproj`), and I reference this in `C`. I do this because many consumers only want `B` but not `C`.

So now if I want to make a change to `B` and debug it, I have to do the following:

1. Build the solution
2. Copy `B.nupkg` from `bin\Debug` to a central location
3. Rebuild the solution again (and possibly clear my NuGet caches)
4. Run

In past, with project references, all I had to do was build and run after chaning `B` and I could step through my newly changed code. How do I get back to the one-click process I had before with project references? Is there a way to use project references in Debug mode and NuGet packages in Release mode?

Comment: If the projects are near to each-other, you can still use project-references, but publish both; that's how most tools tend to be developed

Comment: @MarcGravell - I think I see what you're saying. In my head, I was making things way more complicated than they needed to be. Care to elabororate on what you mean by, "publish both" and put it in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the projects B and C are in the same (or near-enough) location and solution (A); in that case, you're over-complicating this hugely.

Inside the solution, just use project references between B and C (in whichever direction you require). That's absolutely fine and expected - you can debug, build etc B and C together, and everything will work fine, without having to copy anything around *during development*. When you're ready to do a deployment for other consumers (either locally or via CI), just build everything together, making sure that both B and C are configured to generate NuGet packages (it sounds like you've already done this), and upload/copy both NuGet packages to your NuGet store, at the same time.

In the output nupkg files, the project references will be translated to NuGet package references automatically; you don't need to do anything.